# How to move a system to cloud?

Tags: mysql, azure, cloud

I am new to moving systems to cloud. I have done some research so I roughly knows the concept of cloud computing.

Now I need to move a web system to the public cloud(It is my final year project ), but I really got very little clue of:

1. What are the good public cloud resources available out there except for Amazon.
2. How long would the process take to move to cloud?
3. Would the process involve a lot of technical knowledge,i.e. to know how the detailed code is in order to shift to cloud?

Here is the basic info of the websit:

Finished and able to run on local server and DB

- Using MySQL ASP.NET
- Written in C#
- Using MVC concept

Thank you very much for any insights or suggestion. Really Thank you.

Comment: If you have voted down, the reason is also welcome. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can move your project into the cloud of Azure.

In azure there are so many services available for maintain the  your project. Basically the following Services is useful to you for moving into the cloud

1)  Move **JS, Images, CSS** TO  **CDN**

Reason for this:
•        Reduces web server load
•        Improves caching

2)  **SQL** to **Azure Sql DB**

Reason for this:
•        High availability / Failover
•        History
•        Scalability
•        Simple management

3)  **Web site(MVC Application)** to **Azure website**

Reason for this:
•        Less management
•        Elastic Scaling

If you are using any Session management then use Radish cache